# How do I get the acquisition channel from the first visit of a visitor with Google Analytics?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, google-analytics, next.js

I’m trying to figure out where my users are coming from. More specifically, I want to know the channel of their **first visit** on our site. For channels, I am using Google Analytics’ default acquisition channels:

- Direct
- Organic Search
- Paid Search
- Referral
- Social

Our site is a Meteor app for logged in users. It is located at in a subdomain (app.example.com). We use Next.js for the main domain (example.com), which has static pages that anyone can see.

Here the use case I’m trying to solve.

When someone first visits the site, I would like to tag them with a cookie that has their acquisition channel. Let’s say they look around the site and then leave without signing up as a user.

When they visit the site a second time, I don’t want the acquisition channel from that visit. I only want the acquisition channel from the first visit.

Let’s say they sign up to become a user on their second visit. I would like to be able get their acquisition channel from their first visit and add this data to their user document on MongoDB.

How would you go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible since you can't set the acquisition channel from code. However, GA supports [multi-channel funnel analysis](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1191180?hl=en) - this may solve your problem directly.

Comment: This [blog post](https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2012/09/06/how-to-save-google-analytics-referrer-data-to-database/) might also be helpful. It describes how to read the GA `__utmz` cookie. You could do that from js on your site and then augment your data model with that information.

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer. Set a cookie, and read it when they sign up